# JSONB difference between ->> & #>>

Tags: postgresql

When performing a query to filter data with WHERE what is the difference between the two:

```
SELECT "username" FROM "users" AS "user" WHERE ("user"."address"#>>'{postcode}') = '123'


SELECT "username" FROM "users" AS "user" WHERE ("user"."address"->>'postcode') = '123'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

`->> text` Get JSON object field as text

```
{"a":1,"b":2}'::json->>'b' = 2
```

`#>> text[]`    Get JSON object at specified path as text

```
'{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json#>>'{a,2}' = 3
```

So you cannot use `->>` with json path, only with simple field

Comment: So #>> is required for deeper lookup, where as ->> is only good for 1 level deep keys?

Comment: @wazzaday yes, sure